# MySQL syntax error | variable = variable + interger

Tags: mysql, syntax

Hi I have written this MySQL stored proc and I keep getting this syntax error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@start := @start + 3600;

END WHILE;

@start = 1505469600;
' at line 42
```

Here is my stored procedure, I haven't been able to run it yet because of the syntax errors so there might be a few things wrong with it. If you spot any, it would be really helpful if you could help me.

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_zone_time_range_data()

BEGIN

SET @start = 1505469600, @end = 1505483940;

WHILE @start < @end DO

    WHILE @start < @end DO

        INSERT INTO daily_stats_zone_visitors_time_range
        (
            day_epoch,
            day_of_week,
            time_range_hours,
            venue_id,
            visitors,
            visitors_new
        )
        SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(ts,'%Y-%m-%d')) AS day_epoch,
        FROM_UNIXTIME(ts,'%W') AS day_of_week,
        FROM_UNIXTIME(@start, '%h') + '-' + FROM_UNIXTIME(@end, '%h') AS time_range_hours,
        venue_id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT mac) AS visitors,
        COUNT(id) AS visitors_new
        FROM (              
            SELECT probe_request.venue_id,
            probe_request.mac,
            macs.id,
            probe_request.ts
            FROM probe_request
            LEFT OUTER JOIN daily_stats_venue_mac_cache AS macs
            ON probe_request.mac = macs.mac
            AND probe_request.venue_id = macs.venue_id
            AND macs.first_seen BETWEEN @start AND @end
            WHERE probe_request.ts BETWEEN @start AND @end
            GROUP BY probe_request.venue_id, probe_request.mac
        ) AS temp
        GROUP BY venue_id;

        @start = @start + 3600;

    END WHILE;

    @start = 1505469600;
    @end = @end - 3600;

END WHILE;

END;
;;
```

I added the `DELIMITER ;;` to the top of my script because I kept getting a syntax error when I was setting my variables and this seemed to fix it. In all honesty I have no idea why but that bit seems to work now.

I don't have any results to should you because of the error so sorry about that.Thanks for the help in advance it is much appreciated

Comment: Make it `SET @start = 1505469600;`. Same for `@end = ...`.

Comment: `@start := @start + 3600`

Comment: @Forward I have made that change and I am getting the same error

Comment: @fancyPants I have done that and I am getting the same error

Comment: The error is just before the fragment of query displayed by MySQL in the error message.

Comment: @axiac I have edited the question to add the entire error message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set value into variable you have to use Set keyword.

Here it will be

```
   set @start = @start + 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL documentation about [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) says:

> One way to set a user-defined variable is by issuing a [`SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html) statement:
>
> ```
> SET @var_name = expr [, @var_name = expr] ...
> ```
>
> For [`SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html), either [`=`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-equal) or [`:=`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value) can be used as the assignment operator.
>
> You can also assign a value to a user variable in statements other than [`SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html). In this case, the assignment operator must be [`:=`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value) and not [`=`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-equal) because the latter is treated as the comparison operator [`=`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-equal) in non-`SET` statements:
>
> ```
> mysql> SET @t1=1, @t2=2, @t3:=4;
> mysql> SELECT @t1, @t2, @t3, @t4 := @t1+@t2+@t3;
> ```

The line:

```
@start = @start + 3600;
```

is not a valid MySQL statement (and it is not valid even with `:=` instead of `=`). The correct way to assign a value to the variable `@start` in this context is to use a `SET` statement:

```
SET @start = @start + 3600;
```

The same for the other two assignments:

```
SET @start = 1505469600;
SET @end = @end - 3600;
```